# Spring ApplicationContext takes long time to load beans

Tags: spring, javabeans, loading, applicationcontext

I'm having nearly 20 bean files and each of these file is having around 300 beans in it. The bean types are same in all 20 bean files but with different values.

I've created one more common bean file and imported these 20 bean into it and giving this common bean file as location to ApplicationContext(FileSystemApplicationContext) to create beans.

1st few bean files are loaded in millisecs - say till 6 files
and few bean files are loaded in one sec - say till 10 files
and few bean files are loaded in 4 secs - say till 15 files
and final few bean files are loaded in 8 secs - say till 20 files

I've captured these behavior in spring log files.

why is bean loading time gradually increasing when we loading the bean files. Is this an expected behavior?. Number of beans and bean files are going to grow in my application so with this behavior my application startup time is shooting up which is not accepted.

Is there is any spring configuration I can change to load the huge bean file with around 2000 beans in it ?

Any help will be really appreciable.

Regards,
Arun V

Comment: Try playing around with the memory of your JVM by increasing and see if it makes any difference. Also it would be worth attaching jconsole/jvisualvm to the process and see if this is caused by combination of less memory and a full GC cycle. If you cannot use jconsole/jvisualvm, you can enable the gc output (via jvm parameters) and can study the output generated.